# Model Delete Record Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, transactions, jsbin

I have reproduced in this [example](http://jsbin.com/yiwugi/9/edit?html,js,output) my problem, i have created the actions to add and remove transactions in an invoice, the problem is that in my Ember-data the transaction removed is not deleted in the record.

this the code where i am doing something not correct

```
  actions: {
    add: function() {

      var transactionRecord = this.store.createRecord('transaction', {
        name: 'new transaction', 
        isChecked: false
      }); 

      return this.get("model.transactions").addObject(transactionRecord);
    },

   remove: function() {
      var allSelectedItems = this.get("model.transactions").filterBy("isChecked", true);
      return this.get('model.transactions').removeObjects(allSelectedItems).deleteRecord(transactionRecord);
    },
  }

<td><button {{action "add"}}>Add New Transaction</button>
<button {{action "remove"}}>Remove Transaction</button></td>
```

Although i am able to remove the transaction object, when i debug i can still see the transaction in the record data

The transaction to be deleted is the one checked

I attach the images showing the issue:

Before Delete

[image: Before Delete]

After Delete

[image]

As you can see the num transactions is still 3 after removing it

What i am doing wrong in deleting the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to iterate over the array and delete each record individually:

```
remove: function() {
      var allSelectedItems = this.get("model.transactions").filterBy("isChecked", true);
      this.get('model.transactions').removeObjects(allSelectedItems)

      allSelectedItems.forEach(function(item) {
          item.deleteRecord();
      });
    }
```

Also, actions never return anything so no need for the `return`.